# Tridion Sites 9.6 Multiple ecl items in RichTech only resolves one ecl

Tags: dxa, ecl, dxa2.2, sites-9.6

We are using Tridion Sites 9.6 also we have installed dxa-2.2 on CM

recently we came across the issue when we have multiple ecl items attached to the rich text field, but it doesn't resolve  other ecl items,

if we have image, pdf, and word in one rich text field it only resolves the image
if we have pdf, word then it resolves the pdf file

we have used the following XML tag on Render Component Content and Render Page Content tbb

```
<schemasToEmbedInRichText>ExternalContentLibraryStubSchema</schemasToEmbedInRichText>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Does it expand those linked components in RTF fields? can you please preview the page output in CMS and check?